# Drawing a solution curve at a point that is between 2 horizontal asymtote?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, slope

I was wondering how would one draw a solution curve that passes through a point sandwich (but spaced apart) between $2$ horizontal asymptotes? This is assuming that the gradient between the $2$ are constant so a linear line. I inserted an image from Khanacademy below to help with the visualisation, but I'm thinking how would I draw the solution curve that, for example passes through $(0,2)$ when every gradient is the same. In the image below, the curve plateau as y approaches $4$ and continues to approach the gradient of $0$ as $x$ increases to infinity. However, if all gradients was equalled to $3$ between $0<y<4$, would the solution curve be a linear line of $y= 3x$ that passes through $(0,2)$ just stop abruptly before hitting $y=0,y=4$? since there's no sign of the gradient decreasing to illustrate a plateau? Feels a bit off when drawing it out, since at $y=0$ and $y=4$, it represents at change from increasing to decreasing (vice versa) right? Thanks   [image]

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/876009)

Comment: I would use it if it was applicable, such as writing equations to make it easier to visualise. Unless you mean to put it in to every number like $y=3$ ?

Comment: What does $ \ \frac{dy}{dx} \ $ equal at $ \ y = 4 \ $ ?  This tells you that the solution curve has a horizontal asymptote there.  (The closer $ \ y \ $ gets to $ \ 4 \ \ , $ the slower $ \ y \ $ increases.)  The differential equation tells you that the "gradient" is not constant, but only has its largest positive value for $ \ y = 2 \ $ ; it is smaller both as $ \ y \ $ is closer to both $ \ y = 0 \ $ and $ \ y = 4 \ \ . $  Between those lines, the solution curve is a _sigmoid function_. [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function ]

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply since it is a first order differential equation if you are given one point on the curve then the entire curve is completely defined. Solving the equations gives $$\frac{|y|}{|4-y|}=ce^{\frac23x}$$

You put $(0,2)$ to find $c$ and plot $$\frac{|y|}{|4-y|}=e^{\frac23x}$$ which looks like https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dlhx9lk2jn